# Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.2.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bundler

I'm trying to get Rails up and running. I'm able to run `bundle install` successfully, but when I attempt to start the server using `rails s` I get the following message:

```
Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.2.2.0 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'simple_form'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    # The following three gems are used for Bootstrap
    # See: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
    #NOTE: For therubyracer, run "gem install libv8" and "gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'"

end



gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta8'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem "less-rails"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'


gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by adding a gem into the gem file with a capital letter before running bundle install. Look over that you dont have any capital letters with the gems you are adding.

**Should look like this:**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

**Should not look like this:**

```
gem 'Bootstrap-sass'
```